# Flash As3 TextField <br/> is not working

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am using TextField in that Line break is not working 
 i given multiline property to true also. even though i am not getting line break.

how to do 
 using textfield in flash AS3.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Add 
textFieldName.condenseWhite = true;
textFieldName.multiline = true;

Answer (score 1):

whenever you get texts from an external files like XML. if there is a one line breaks in your [!CDATA] content then you will get two line breaks in your Flash Text Field (It's a BUG). the solution is, before assigning text to TextField you need to search line breaks charactor. when you use ("/n") in XML that it comes in ("//n"), but it will be displayed as \n.
I do one of these `str.split("\\n").join("\n")` after I get the string from the xml.

Answer (score 1):

```
 var txt:TextField = new TextField();
    txt.multiline = true;
    txt.htmlText = "benny<br>geo";
    addChild(txt);
```

For more to know about htmlText click [here](http://www.designswan.com/archives/tags-support-in-htmltext-flash-as3.html).

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to wrap the words. You should set **wordWrap** parameter to true.

**multiline** parameter only says, whether it should respect "\n" in text or cut them out. There is a bug in Flash - **multiline** works only when **type** parameter is "input".

BTW. all you can display with **htmlText** you can also display without it (i.e. you can fully implement **htmlText** above TextField by yourself).

Answer (score 0):

add a \n to the text where you want a newline, should work!

Comment: no \n is also not working its showing \n itself..not recognizing as escape character.

Comment: thats because its /n not \n, sorry my bad :D

Comment: the /n is also not working but <br/> is working ,but there is lot of space in between line break ... is there any way to avoid that unwanted space..

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
<br>
```

instead:

```
<br/>
```

or:

```
</br>
```